# Using a Range object with NewEnum() instead of Collection class (ie with For Each)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a custom collection class, Record.

I've currently enabled enumeration of my class by:

```
private pRecord as Collection

'
' Enables enumeration of the pRecords Collection (ie using For Each).
'
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Attribute NewEnum.VB_MemberFlags = "40"

    Set NewEnum = pRecord.[_NewEnum]
End Property
```

Currently, pRecord is a Collection containing individual cells that is in a row of some Range object, eg Range("A1:C6").Rows(1).

Is it possible to set the actual row Range as the object that is enumerated instead of the the pRecords collection?  If so, how do you do it?

I figure that this must be possible some how as you can already use For Each on range objects.

Comment: Wouldn't you be enumerating over cells either way?  Are you working from this http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/07/04/custom-collection-class/  (or something similar) ?

Comment: @Tim Williams, yeah, that website explains custom collections very nicely.  I am looking to improve the efficiency of my code.  As Range is already a collection, I should be able to use it in place of pRecord.  But I cant see any _NewEnum property in the range class.

Comment: The alternative is that I create a method that returns the row (Ie Property Get Row() as Range) and use For Each with that.  That would work fine, but that still leaves me wondering how to use Range instead of Collection in the NewEnum property.

Comment: Have you tried just substituting a Range object for your collection?

Comment: @Tim Williams, I just tried your suggestion.  I can't believe I missed it.  I changed 'Set NewEnum = pRecord.[_NewEnum]' to Set NewEnum = Range("A1:D1").[_NewEnum] and the For Each loop did indeed loop through the range object.  If you put it up as the solution I'll tick it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried substituting a Range object for your collection?